# is there any way to set breakpoints on all lines that contain certain word ? Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints

my program got some bugs and i wasn't able to find out where the bug is. 
I am thinking to set a bunch of breakpoints to all the lines that contain a certain word.